# How do I restrict an amazon AWS Product Advertising item search to JUST amazon.co.uk (ie NOT amazon.com)

Tags: python, amazon-product-api, bottlenose

Using "[bottlenose](https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose)" - ( http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottlenose/0.3.4 )

Here's my code:

```
import bottlenose,json

AMAZON_SECRET_KEY="XXX"
AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXX"
AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG="XXX"
tmd = "B00005UQVU"
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)
ResponseGroup="Offers",SearchIndex="Books", IdType="ISBN", Style="http://xml2json-xslt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xml2json.xslt")
response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId=tmd, ResponseGroup="Offers", Condition="Used", \
        # MarketplaceDomain="????", SearchIndex="????",  \
        Style="http://xml2json-xslt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xml2json.xslt")
```

`print response
d = json.loads(response)    
print d["ItemLookupResponse"]["Items"]["Item"]["OfferSummary"]["LowestUsedPrice"]`

I would like to see the results from this page:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Truly-Madly-Deeply-Juliet-Stevenson/dp/B00005UQVU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1331911657&sr=8-1

NOT this page:

[http://www.amazon.com/Truly-Madly-Deeply-Juliet-Stevenson/dp/B00005UQVU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1331911657&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00005UQVU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 minutes later I found it:

.. add Region="UK" into the bottlenose.Amazon() call.